# Output for the Javascript function

Tags: javascript, output

```
<script>
 var num1=100;
 function test(){
    num2=200;
    var num1=300;
    num1=num2;
 }
 test();
 document.write(num1 +"-"+num2);
 </script>
```

The output is 100-200. How is that possible...Someone please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use var to declare a function, its scope is limited to the current execution context. That means that inside your function, you are declaring a new variable `num1` which has scope limited to the function `test`, instead of actually modifying the global variable.

This means that when you go to access the `num1` variable to write it to the document, you are accessing the one in the global scope, which has not actually changed.

To make your function modify the global variable, you simply need to remove the keyword `var` from your function. This tells javascript that you are changing the global variable `num1`, rather than creating a new variable limited to the `test` function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have redeclared the `num1` inside the `test` scope, so when you change the value of `num1` inside the `test` scope, the `num1` in the global scope wont be changed.

check this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript) it might help you understand javascript scopes.

Answer (score 0):

`num1 +"-" + num2`:
Are you expecting the difference as in num1-num2?
If so, this won't work:
The string `"-"` in the middle forces the whole thing to become a string.
If that's what you wanted - excuse me... :)

See other people's answers about scope of vars.